# Происхождение слова "шалопай"

Tags: этимология

Вот интересно, "шало-" - видимо, родственное слову "шалость". А "-пай"? Интересно было бы узнать происхождение этого слова полностью.
Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В 18 веке в русском языке начинают широко применяться слова шалить, шалеть, шалун, шалость, шаловливый. Все они восходят к  о.-с. "шалый", семантически близкому к слову "резвый" (и.-е. основа  от (s)hel - резать).

Слово "шалопай" впервые отмечено в комедиях в конце 18 века, например: "Лучше век просижу в девках, чем пойду за такого шалопая" (Николаев, "Розана и Любим", 1776 год).

Схема образования: шалый - шалопа (утр.) - шалопан (диал.) - шалопай, сравнить: горлопа - горлопан.

По другой версии слово заимствовано из французского языка: chenepan (фр. ) - хулиган, лодырь, от  Schnapphahn (старонем.) - грабитель, разбойник. Например, у Достоевского (1864 год):" Я для вас просто гаденький человек, шенапан". Затем: шенапан - шелапан - шалопай.

Answer (score 0):

А мне почему-то видится связь слова ШАЛОПАЙ со словом САЛОП . Помните у Вл.Маяковского в поэме "Хорошо" ? - "Салоп говорит чуйке , чуйка салопу - заерзали длинноносые щуки , скоро всех слопают !" Здесь у Маяковского слово САЛОП употреблено иносказательно , в смысле - ограниченный по уму мещанин (то же самое и по слову чуйка) . САЛОП - это , в общем значении , разновидность одежды . Но имеются и другие смыслы на этот корень . **///** *САЛОП - а, м. ист. Широкое женское пальто с пелериной, с прорезями для рук или с короткими рукавами. Са-лопница (пренебр. устар. ) - 1) женщина в изношенном платье, в старом салопе; 2) перен. женщина с  мещански-обывательским кругозором, сплетница. Салопный - относящийся к салопу, салопам. (Словарь иностранных слов)* **///**  То есть : если САЛОПНИЦА это тупая мещанка-сплетница женского рода , то САЛОП-АЙ = ШАЛОПАЙ это нечто схожее , только уже в мужском роде .

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что слово "шалопай" резко негативного смысла сегодня (да и в прошлом) не несёт. Совершенно не вяжется с франц. "хулиган" и тем более  старонемецким "грабитель, разбойник". Смысл: легкомысленный, безответственный,склонный к озорству и т.п.. Скорее всего связано происхождением с "шалить".

Answer (score 0):

Французское выражение "chad lapin'  [шолапа],  дословный перевод " горячий кролик",  в русском переводе соответсвует нашему " Казанова", гуляка, что является близким значению слову "шалопай".

Comment: Во-первых, у вас ошибка, горячий - Chaud, во-вторых, "Казанова" тут не совсем точно, правильнее сказать - *похотливый развратник, "кобель".*. И самое главное: "шалопай" это совсем не оно, значение все-таки другое. Такое переход смысла сомнителен и уж - как минимум - требует объяснения.